# Prove $\lambda_a(x)=ax$ is a product of $[G:\left\langle a\right\rangle]$ cycles of length $\text{order }a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Given is that $G$ is a finite group. Define $\lambda_a\colon G\to G$ by $\lambda_a=ax$ for $x\in G$. Proof that $\lambda_a$ is a product of $[G:\left\langle a\right\rangle]$ disjunct cycles of length $\text{order }a$.

I can prove that $G\cong\Lambda$ where $\Lambda=\{\lambda_a : a \in G\}$ (with the regular function composition operation). But I am not sure if this helps me. But, the isomorphism does imply that $\text{order }\Lambda=\text{order } G=[G:\left\langle a\right\rangle]\cdot \text{order }a$.

How to continue?

Comment: You already know it is a product of disjoint cycles with order dividing the order of $a$, just because it is a permutation. Now, follow an element through the permutation applied over and over, how long does it take to get back to itself, i.e., when does $a^k x = x$?

Comment: This is of course exactly for $k=\text{order }a$. This means that the order of $\lambda_a$ is indeed $\text{order } a$. And then this indeed consists of $[G:\left\langle a\right\rangle]$ cycles. It was not a smart step to directly go into the isomorphisms, as that made me forget about the permutations itself.

Comment: So the disjoint cycles of length the order of $a$ (call it n) are of the form $(x, ax, a^2x, \ldots, a^{n-1}x)$, basically the ordered cosets of the cyclic subgroup $\langle a\rangle$.